# boolean variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have some issues. I have checkbox in my jsp page. So if the checkbox is checked i have to set a boolean variable to true else false. I tried something like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".confirmCheckbox").change(function() {
        boolean confirmAssignee = false;
        $(this).attr("checked") {
            confirmAssignee = true;
        }
        alert(confirmAssignee);
    });
});
```

But it is giving this error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
$(this).attr("checked") {
```

I have mutliple checkboxes on the page.  Sample code is like this :

```
for loop(----)
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmBox-${loopCounter.index}" class = "confirmCheckbox">
```

Any help will be appreciated. Ask anything if required.

Comment: use `var`, instead of `boolean`

Comment: js var definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `var` while defining variable and use `this.checked` or `.prop()` to get whether checkbox is checked or not.

Simple statement will do it.

```
var confirmAssignee = this.checked; //OR $(this).prop("checked");
```

Complete Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".confirmCheckbox").change(function() {
        var confirmAssignee = false;

        if (this.checked) {
            confirmAssignee = true;
        }
        alert(confirmAssignee);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not **boolean** type use `var`

*Change*

```
boolean confirmAssignee = false;
```

*To*

```
var confirmAssignee = false;
```

You also miss the if in the state `$(this).attr("checked") {` it should be `if($(this).attr("checked")) {`

**Note** use prop for checkbox instead of attr as suggest be [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType,
>   ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved
>   and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties
>   were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the
>   scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties.

You can simplify code like

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qv412qnh/)

```
$(".confirmCheckbox").change(function () {   
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript have auto data types you didn't need to declare data types it is automatically taken in javascript. To check the checkbox using  **`this.checked`**

```
 $(".confirmCheckbox").change(function () {
        var confirmAssignee = false;

        if (this.checked) {

            confirmAssignee = true;
        }
        alert(confirmAssignee);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problem in your code
one there is no boolean datatype in javascript use var instead of boolean

secondly you need to check if checkbox is checked or not in if condition

use below code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$( ".confirmCheckbox" ).change(function() {

var confirmAssignee = false;
if($(this).attr("checked")) {

}
alert(confirmAssignee);
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1)use `var`  instead of of boolean

`var confirmAssignee = false;`

2)use checkbox checked property

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
```